# Missing whitespace in combobox

Tags: html, select, whitespace

My code:

```
<select><option value='3'>0000000000000001                 11121</option></select>
```

I want to get combo box with spaces between two numbers, however all I get is the same as this:

```
<select><option value='3'>0000000000000001 11121</option></select>
```

Can someone advice how to get additional whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you can put `&nbsp;` inside your tag like this:

```
<select><option value='3'>0000000000000001 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 11121</option></select>
```

White spaces aren't interpreted by html

It is essentially a standard space, the primary difference being that a browser should not break (or wrap) a line of text at the point that this   occupies.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vLGdK/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill area not with space symbol but with `&nbsp;`.

`&nbsp;` is the entity used to represent a non-breaking space.

So try this:

```
<select><option value='3'>0000000000000001 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 11121</option></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add spaces to your text, you can use the `&nbsp;` character entity.

Try this:

```
<select><option value='3'>0000000000000001&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;11121</option>
</select>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dP9R9/)